# How to not display decimal places unless necessary with DecimalFormat

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

I'm modifying the following code to format doubles: "###,##0.#########". It generally works the way it should, but when I have a number like "123", it displays it as "123.0". How do I get it to avoid outputting the decimal place in that case? I just want "123" to show up.

After reading the Java tutorial, it seems as though it shouldn't display anything after the decimal place because everything after the decimal place in the formatting string is a pound sign, not a 0. But it's not behaving that way.

Also, why is the 0 there in the first place, *before* the decimal place, in the formatting string?

Edit: my full code is as follows. I'm new-ish to this project and still trying to figure out why it does this:

```
textField = new TextField("field", Double.class) {
    public org.apache.wicket.util.convert.IConverter getConverter(
            Class type) {
        DoubleConverter converter = (DoubleConverter) DoubleConverter.INSTANCE;
        java.text.NumberFormat numberFormat = converter
                .getNumberFormat(getLocale());
        java.text.DecimalFormat decimalFormat = (java.text.DecimalFormat) numberFormat;
        decimalFormat.applyPattern("###,##0.#########");
        converter.setNumberFormat(getLocale(),
                decimalFormat);
        return converter;
    };
};
```

Comment: Using your format string in `DecimalFormat`, I get the `double` value to print as `123`, not `123.0`.

Comment: @rgettman , you're right. I just tested the same thing in a separate test program I wrote. But it looks like that's not all that's going on. I've pasted the full code above.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider restating the problem then? It would seem to be something going on in the wicket code, not the `DecimalFormat` code. Have you tried putting a debugging breakpoint in `DecimalFormat.format()`? See where and when it actually gets called, and what the state of affairs is at that point?

Answer (score -1):

The reason you're getting a 0 after the answer, is because you have set the answer to be a *double*. Doubles are set to be decimal answers. If there is nothing there to be a decimal answer, it will automatically place it as a 0, because there must be something after the decimal place.

If you want to get rid of the 0 after the answer, the simplest way would be to change the answer to an integer. However using an if statement to check whether it has only one 0 after the decimal place, would allow you to have both an integer answer and a double answer.

Comment: Did you test what you wrote? Because you are wrong - if you use a `DecimalFormat` whose pattern is set to `###,##0.#######` and format `123.0` you will get `123`. Not `123.0`.